# Initialization in node.js || How to handle initial configuration in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I recently transited from Java to JavaScript specifically MEAN Stack Development. I want to make API in node.js such that it initializes all configuration upon deployment like **init** method in Servlets.

If there is any other standardized way to accomplish this task kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go with [Loopback](https://loopback.io/) is a highly-extensible, open-source Node.js API framework.

**Features**

> - Quickly create dynamic end-to-end REST APIs.
> - Connect devices and browsers to data and services.
> - Use Android, iOS, and AngularJS SDKs to easily create client apps.
> - Add-on components for push, file management, 3rd-party login, and geolocation.
> - Use StrongLoop Arc to visually edit, deploy, and monitor LoopBack apps.
> - StrongLoop API Gateway acts an intermediary between API consumers (clients) and API    providers to externalize, secure, and manage
>     APIs.
> - Runs on-premises or in the cloud

**How to install** - To install this, simply run the following given command.

```
$ npm install -g strongloop
```

*Hope this will help to resolve your query !!*

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) which provides many tools for configuring, representing and validating a RESTful API.

There is a [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) module which, after defining your JSON API schema, can automatically configure your API for you.